# Javascript multiple countdown timer

Tags: javascript, css, timer, countdown

I have been trying for days to get this work. 
So i want this countdown timer to print multiple timers, and the dates comes in one specific txt file.

Here is my code.

index.php

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title> TimTo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="javas/countdown.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<?php 
$myfile=file("kellonaika.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) or die("Unable to locate the file!");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myfile); $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class='clockdiv'>
        <div>
            <span class='days'></span>
                <div class='smalltext'>Days</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class='hours'></span>
                <div class='smalltext'>Hours</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class='minutes'></span>
                <div class='smalltext'>Minutes</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class='seconds'></span>
                <div class='smalltext'>Seconds</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
</body>
<?php echo"<script>initializeClock('clockdiv',". $myfile[$i] .");</script>"; } ?>
</html>
```

countdown.js

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}  
function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
  clock.style.display = 'block';
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

And here is my stylesheet
styles.css

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #00ECB9;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 50;
}
h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 50;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}
.clockdiv {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}
.clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}
.smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And my kellonaika.txt is like this
'2016-06-23'
'2016-12-31'
'2016-12-31'
'2016-12-31'
'2016-12-31'
'2016-12-31'

Comment: What works and what doesn't?

Comment: It does shows the background of the clock ( divs ) but the numbers aren't running and even not showing.

Comment: If you replicate the issue in a jsfiddle it'd be easier to help

Comment: Is your javascript being run?